# Excel 2013 copy conditional formatting in all cells of a column rising

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel 2013. I need conditional formatting dependent on a condition: If cell L2 is not empty and cell `M2` is not empty format cell `D2` with background color.

I tried `=AND($L2>0,$M2>0)` to apply to cell `D2` and it works fine.

Now I want cell `D3` to get the rule `=AND($L3>0,$M3>0)`.

I need that for hundreds of rows, so I don't want to make it by hand. So in the conditional format manager I added `Applies to =$D$2:$D$300`.

But now suddenly all this cells have the new background color, even if both values of column `L` and column `M` of the same row are empty.

Also using the format brush and selecting all cells in column `D` made them coloured.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: When you open Conditional Formatting, Manage Rules...  Is there only one Rule listed under Current Selection and This Worksheet?  =AND($L3>0,$M3>0) and your Applies to are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting can be a pain like that.  You can use Format Painter to copy the first row's conditional formatting and paste on the remaining rows.  And if your formula contains relative address, it will be applied properly.